# How do I hide a single subdocument in a MongoDB aggregation pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, projection

On a `find()` query you can hide fields with the *projection* document in the second argument:

```
var cursor = collection.find(query, {
    '_id': false,
    'unwanted': false
});
```

It will return whatever fields and sub-documents are in the document. This makes sense.

Why are the rules different when you put this `projection` document into an `aggregation pipeline`? `$project` doesn't work the same:

```
var cursor = collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match      : query
    },
    {
        $project    : {
        '_id': false,
        'unwanted': false
        }
    }
]);
```

Problem:

```
exception: The top-level _id field is the only field currently supported 
for exclusion
```

How do I hide a specific sub-document without resorting to *explicitly including* all the fields I want?

**edit:** The documents have an arbitrary amount of fields without a defined schema, apart from some indexed fields. So I *can't* specify what I want to include, because I *don't know* what extra fields are going to be in the document.

Imagine documents with random fields, except for `_id` and an `unwanted` sub-document. I want to remove those two.

---

**update:**

It seems this question is unclear, because the logic is discussed rather than the problem. So let me illustrate an inefficient solution:

```
// node.js

var cursor = collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match     : query
    },
    // ...
]);

cursor.toArray(function(array){
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var document = array[i];
        delete document._id;
        delete document.unwanted;
    }
})
```

I don't like this, because there is overhead in rendering a `cursor` to an `array` and is limited to 16MB sized collections. Besides, not having to do this is exactly what the projection document is for.

Hence my question, why can I get my cursor just fine using `find()` with projection, but not using `aggregate()` with the same projection? Where is the logic? The functionality is clearly in the MongoDB adapter, otherwise it wouldn't work with `find()` either. What are possible solutions or workarounds, apart from the one I just mentioned?

I think one solution could be using the `MongoDB 2.6` aggregation function `$redact` but I cannot figure out using the documentation how to simply remove one single static subdocument. Also I prefer not to use this as most of our systems run `MongoDB 2.4`.

Comment: _Downvote_ and _close_ are not meant to be used emotionally, and it's sad to downvote without leaving a constructive comment. I think this is done by the person who removed their own comments. Whether or not you can imagine a use-case for this, why `find` and `aggregate` seem to have a different set of rules for the same stage is apparently a good and hard to answer question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot do that in the aggregation pipeline, and it is clearly defined in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/):

```
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|                Syntax | Description                                              |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|  <field>: <1 or true> | Specify the inclusion of a field.                        |
|     _id: <0 or false> | Specify the suppression of the _id field.                |
| <field>: <expression> | Add a new field or reset the value of an existing field. |
+-----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

The only way to go is as you described:

> resorting to explicitly including all the fields I want

But anyway, you can achieve that, by constructing the `$project` document dynamically, *in case if you have all the possible fields that might appear*. Here is a pseudo code:

```
project_doc = {}
for field in fields
    if field not in to_be_hidden_fields:
        project_doc[field] = "$" + field
return {"$project": project_doc}
```

This works because

> If you specify an inclusion of a field that does not exist in the document, `$project` ignores that field inclusion; i.e. `$project` does not add the field to the document.

And then just add the resulting `$project` stage to your aggregation pipeline.

---

But if you do not know the schema in advance, or not even all the possible fields that the resulting documents might have, I think you should rather **reconsider the design**.

Anyway, another question rises, how are you going to do an aggregation if you don't know the fields? I think this is the reason why MongoDB has eliminated field exclude feature inside `$project`.

Comment: When I said I didn't want to do that, I meant that it's not an option, as the documents can have an arbitrary amount of fields, and there is no defined schema. I want to remove a certain field with metadata, and I need a solution for this. It's bad for resources but is the solution really to convert a cursor to an array and _'bruteforce'_ my way through the documents?

Comment: Since I only know the fields after I have queried all the documents with my pipeline, and I can only execute the pipeline after I know all the fields, this is a catch-22 solution. Am I wrong?

Comment: so you mean you will know what *fields you need to hide* only after you make an aggregation query?

Comment: @Redsandro so correct me if I'm wrong. You know exactly what fields you want to hide, but not the list of all fields, right?

Comment: @Michael yes, that's not possible

Comment: @n9code Exactly! I know what I want to hide because they are guaranteed to be in there, but I don't know what other fields are going to be in the selected documents, so I cannot explicitly include them.

Comment: No. That's precisely the point. I will gather the unknown fields and do something with them.

Comment: where are you going to query from? e.g. `mongo shell`? and is it an option to do the projection on the client side?

Comment: I need to do this serverside, but it's an option to manually do this later. However, this option is ugly (see my latest update). Since we can hide fields and subdocuments using projection in `find()`, the functionality clearly is available in the MongoDB adapter. I just don't get why "they" removed it from the `aggreration()` function.

Comment: _"reconsider the design":_ Imagine a database manager. Does it know all the possible fields a collection might have? I don't have influence over the data. I just need to handle the data. What do you know about `$redact`?

Comment: Hmm...looks interesting, let me take a look and try to suggest something

Comment: But Im afraid there is nothing to do with `$redact` as you have access to only the field values and not names.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78563/discussion-between-n9code-and-redsandro).